# Show div only when click on input

Tags: jquery

How to display a `div` only when I press the input or textarea?

Also, CSS is written correctly? .. or has some errors?

Demo code: http://jsfiddle.net/2wNbR/54/

Thanks for answer!

Comment: You're hiding it on focus, which is backwards from what you say you want. Hide it initially, and *show* it on focus (and hide it on blur). But just posting a link to some code isn't really what SO is about.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are trying to achive. Try to explain a little more.

Comment: Please include the code in the question as well.

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".info_form").hide();
    $("input").on("focus", function () {
        $(".info_form").hide();
        $(this).next('div.info_form').show();
    });
});
```

See here http://jsfiddle.net/2wNbR/58/

--------- EDITED ----------------

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".info_form").hide();
    $("input").on("focus", function () {
        $(".info_form").hide();
        $(this).next('div.info_form').show();
    });

     $(document).click(function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('input')) {
            $(".info_form").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2wNbR/62/

Just add `float:left;` in your `.info_form` class in css. it will stay inline.

Comment: Something like, but why not stay inline? ... and how do you Hide div when clicked outside?

Comment: check updated answer for hiding when clicked outside. For staying it inline. You will need to fix you css.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried hiding it on ready() and show it on click?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".info_form").hide();
    $("input").on("focus", function () {
        $(".info_form").show();

    });
});
```

Comment: It's ok, but I want to display one div, not all

Answer (score 0):

Modified .info_form class and the JS code. Here is the result     `url`
       http://jsfiddle.net/2wNbR/60/

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: happy that you got answer :)